# Conditional content based on url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to show content based on whether a certain tracking url was used to access the page. I have looked into request.referrer, but can't seem to get it to function.

What is the best way to show/hide content using rails for example

Hide for: www.yourcompany.com/web
Show for: www.yourcompany.com/web?test

Answer (score 3):

Check the existence or a match of your param using `params[:name]` in your controller or view:

In your view:

```
<% if param[:param].present? %>
  Some hidden content
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, check in your controller and show in your view:

```
# controller
@hidden_content = "XXX" if param[:param].present?

# view
<%= @hidden_content %>
```